# Powershell Get-ADComputer filter for multiple operating systems

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to filter/match the operating system from `Get-ADComputer` and only return computers that have Windows 7 and above:

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem | Where-Object {operatingsystem -match "*Windows 7*|*Windows 8*|*Windows 10*"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} |
Select-Object -Expand Name
```

but when I do that, the debugger asks for a `-Filter` parameter

I have also tried:

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -filter {(operatingsystem -match "*Windows 7*|*Windows 8*|*Windows 10*")} |
```

but I get an error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: '(operatingsystem -match "*Windows 7*|*Windows 8*|*Windows 10*")' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: 
    -match' at position: '18'.
```

So what's the correct/best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing advanced filtering using `Where-Object` you need to refer to iterator object. Also in your first code example, include `-Filter *` to get a complete list of all machines. I.e. try running

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -Filter * `
    | Where-Object {$_.operatingsystem -match "*Windows 7*|*Windows 8*|*Windows 10*"}
```

Alternatively you can do simple filtering and exclude the `$_` operator like this

```
Get-Process | where name -like svchost
```

However, the `-match` operator does not seem to support this way of filtering.

You can also filtering the returned result when doing the query for all AD computers, like this

```
Get-ADComputer -Properties OperatingSystem `
    -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 7*" -or OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8*"}
```

See this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/14/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter-part-ii/) on what is allowed when doing advanced filtering against Active Directory.

In my opinion, it's worth trying to do as much filtering as possible at the "server" end of the query and only return what you really need. The benefit is that all further processing at your end will be faster since there's less data to process.

Comment: `Get-ADComputer -Properties OperatingSystem '
    -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 7*" -or OperatingSystem -like "*Windows 8*"}` worked, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use multiple `filters` condition with your `Get-AdComputer` cmdlet. Instead of using the `-match` parameter, I would suggest to use `-like` parameter. I am not sure if `Get-AdComputer` supports the `-match` parameter. You can do something like below -

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -filter 'operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*" -or operatingsystem -like "*Windows 8*" -or operatingsystem -like "*Windows 10*"' |
```

If you see `Get-Help Get-ADComputer -Examples`, you can see how the `-filter` parameter is used.